# Leads with required fields that need to be put on hold

Tags: workflow

We're working with a newly designed lead with required fields. The issue that came up is that we have reps who can't always get all of the required info when first creating the lead. Is it possible to use a trigger, like a check box, that the reps can use to set these incomplete leads aside until the required fields can be completed?

Comment: This might work best with 2 Record Types where when the lead status is updated or a check box is completed a workflow changes the Record Type and the page layout for the second RT has the other fields as required.

Comment: The solution provided by Dave is perfect. Another solution can be to auto populate default values to required fields at the start. You can check the following link as a reference http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

This might be easiest to implement by having 2 Record Types with different page layouts and a workflow that changes the record type when a checkbox is ticked.

**Record Type 1**
Initial lead - has only minimum set of required fields on page layout.
Checkbox on layout when ticked triggers Workflow to update Record Type from Initial Lead to Complete Lead.

**Record Type 2**
Complete lead - has full set of required fields on page layout.